# Proof: basis and linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $v_1,...,v_k \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$, then for every $m \geq 1$ and any $u_1,...,u_k \in \mathbb{R}^m$, there exists a unique $m\times n$ matrix A such that $u_j = Av_j$, for $j=1,...,k$.

Proof:
Assume $v_1,...,v_k \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $k=n$

Let $B$ be $n \times n$ matrix with cols $v_1,...,v_n$, then $B$ is invertible.

Let $C$ be $m \times n$ with cols $u_1,...,u_k$
Since $k=n$, $u_j=Av_j$ for $j=1,...,k$ and $C=AB$

We can get $A=CB^{-1}$, as we expected

Am I correct?

Comment: Why not write $n$ instead of $k$?

Comment: You proved existence, not uniqueness. You also should verify direct that your choice of $A$ works for completeness.

Comment: How to prove uniqueness?

Comment: Assume there are $A_1,A_2\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ such that $A_1v_j=u_j$ and $A_2v_j=u_j$ for $j=1,2,...,k$. Show $A_1=A_2$.